# Unreliable pressure transducer readings

Tags: arduino, voltage, transducer

I have a relatively simple setup where I have an Arduino Mega reading a pressure transducer ([transducer specs](https://sensing.honeywell.com/MLH08KPSB01A-Stainless-Steel-Media-Isolated-Pressure-Sensors)) and then I'm just watching the voltage readings over serial. It seems that I'm getting bad readings because I'm getting voltages from 2.1 to 3.5 without any pressure beyond ambient and this transducer reads from 0-8000psi so something is quite wrong if it is reading ~4000psi. Below is my Arduino code. And I have the circuit schematic below as well. In my circuit I have the leads from the pressure ducer directly into the Arduino and they are around 30cm long. Let me know if any more information would be useful, does anyone have ideas as to why I would be getting wonky readings and what I can do to chase down this bug? I have done this setup on two separate but identical pressure transducers with the same result.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int press1 = A0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600); // set the baud rate
  Serial.println("Starting code");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println("Running code. Voltage is:");
  int sensorValue = analogRead(press1);
  float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  Serial.println(voltage); 
  delay(2000);
}
```

[image: schematic]

Comment: Which *exact* model are you using?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm using model # MLH08KPSB01A and when looking at page 5 here: https://sensing.honeywell.com/honeywell-sensing-heavy-duty-pressure-transducers-mlh-series-datasheet-008118-8-en.pdf you can see all the specifics of that model

Answer (score 1):

First disconnect the Vout from Arduino and measure it with a multimeter to make sure the sensor is fine by itself.  If it's weird without the Arduino then make a final check that V+ (while attached to the Arduino) is 5 V.  If that all checks out then you have deeper issues.

I've use similar Honeywell pressure sensors for projects and in one case I needed to amplify the output up to 10 V but because the input impedance on my amplifier was too low the pressure sensor output started oscillating.  I can't remember the details but I remember being surprised at how poor its drive strength was (it was easy to overload it).  So you might look at the circuit on the Arduino and make sure that Vout directly connects to the microcontroller without any extra loading (like resistors to ground or Vcc).

Comment: Okay so I finally had the chance to look into this some more and I am getting 5V between V+ and V-. I'm not really getting any reading on the Vout and when I have Vout unplugged from the Arduino it doesn't change the reading. So I assume I have some sort of floating value. Any further thoughts?

Comment: What voltage specifically is Vout when not attached to the Arduino?

Comment: It is usually bouncing around between 2 and 3 volts. And it is almost the exact same when it is attached to the Arduino.

Comment: Well if the V+ is stable then your pressure sensor is bad since it should be outputting ~0.5 V without pressure.  My next step would be to try a new sensor.  Also I'm assuming that A0 in your schematic connects directly to ADC0 on the Mega?  That "RX0" note is odd - is that pin also connected to digital I/O?  If so I'd move the Vout to a pin that can't possibly be driven by the microcontroller.